# Enter a portal via Crm user in salesfoce

Tags: salesforce, crm, portal

There is any way to enter my portal site with crm user insteed of portal user?

thanks a-lot!.

Menashe Yamin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no.

This is the way the portals are designed to work: a pair user and contact with the contact linked on activation to an associated portal user.
You can though log as a Portal user from the Salesforce UI (on the related Contact detail page) to see things from your portal user eyes.

Hope this helps.

Cheers

Fab